# Use HTTP request to create column with formatting schema in power automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am creating columns in SharePoint list with "Send An HTTP request". I am wondering if I can also send formatting column json schema as a part of request content body (or any other way from power automate).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can do it in the action you use to create the column, i tried it and it works. I recommend you to configure the JSON custom formatter directly in sharepoint list/library and then minify the code.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I still didn't solve it completely! I am using IF in my schema. This raise 400 BadRequest `InvalidClientQueryException: "Invalid JSON. A comma character ',' was expected in scope 'Object'. Every two elements in an array and properties of an object must be separated by commas.`
I assume it has to do with the fact if need single quote and request JSON as well. I am struggling to find the way to escape them.

Comment: Here is my schema https://imgur.com/0aZDr45
It works correctly in SharePoint list if I add it by hand

Comment: When you initialize the variable, could you try to surround your code with ' character.

Comment: Yeah. I did this from the start: https://imgur.com/izy54T9
I am pretty sure the problem is that `if` statement in JSON for formatting is only accepting single quote while request body use single quotes for parameters

Comment: I tested it, and yes, the problem is inside the if statement, i fixed it by replacing every `'` inside all IF's with `\'`. And I think it's missing one closing parentheses to close the third IF.

Comment: BIG thank you!! It works! That was actually first thing I tried to escape, but obviously made a mistake!